# Generating a small circle inside a big circle and produce different random numbers in their radius

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to generate a small circle with radius r and center other than (0,0)inside a big circle with radius s and center (0,0) & produce different number of random points inside them?For example, 10 points within radius r and 100 points within radius s.Could anyone please help?

Comment: How can one circle be in the center of another circle if both have a different center? That is impossible!

Answer (score 2):

Check the following code segment. You may have to update as per your requirement. As an example think of how to avoid crossing circles.

```
clear all;

i = 0;
j = 0;
r = 100;
nc = 2;

figure;
hold on;
axis equal;

viscircles([0 0], r, 'EdgeColor','r')

while i < nc
    rr = randi([-r r]);
    rc = randi([-r r]);
    d = pdist([rc rr; 0 0],'euclidean');
    r2 = randi([20 300]);
    if d<r && d+r2<r
        viscircles([rc rr], r2, 'EdgeColor','g')
        c = [rand rand rand];
        np = randi([1 10]);
        while j<np
            pc = randi([rc-r2 rc+r2]);
            pr = randi([rr-r2 rr+r2]);
            d2 = pdist([pc pr; rc rr],'euclidean');
            if d2<r2
                scatter(pc,pr,30,c,'filled');
                j = j+1;
            end
        end
        i = i+1;
    end
end
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the code.though didn't try it for  my case.I'll come to you, if I need any further help.